# When are these series equal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose we have a power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_nb_nx^n}$$ When is it true that the series obtained by eliminating $b_n$ is proportional to the original series? $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_nx^n}=c\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_nb_nx^n}\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{for some}\;c\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: If the series has a nonzero radius of convergence then the series defines a function in that interval and the coefficients correspond to its derivatives at $x=0$, hence are unique.

Comment: If $\forall n,b_n=c$, then the equality holds.

Comment: If $a_n=0$ for all values of $n$, then it's true.

Comment: So the only solutions are $b_n=1/c$ or $a_n=0$ is that correct? This question was inspired by something odd that I noticed, but I don't think I generalized it quite right... this seems to be a trivial question. PS post an answer and I'll be glad to accept :)

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar You meant $1/c$ I'm assuming?

Comment: @user142299 Yes, my mistake. Also, equality holds if $a_n=0\forall n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power series with a positive radius of convergence are equal at points other than the center only if all their coefficients match.  So $a_n = c a_n b_n$ for all $n$.

That means for every nonzero value of $a_n$, you have $1 = cb_n$, so $b_n=1/c$.  For values of $n$ for which $a_n=0$, the coefficient $b_n$ could be anything.

For example:
\begin{align}
a & = \text{the sequence } 1,\ 0,\ 2,\ 0,\ 3,\ 0,\ \ldots \\
b & = \text{the sequence } 9, \ 6,\ 9,\ 5,\  9,\  7,\  \ldots \\
c & = 1/9
\end{align}